# Обособление уточнений (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

1) "Неодолимая, хотя и тихая, сила увлекла меня".
2) "Получены важные, хотя и не итоговые сведения".

Почему в первом предложении "хотя и ..." обособляется, а во втором — нет?  В чем между ними разница?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос есть у Розенталя:

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

Уточняющие определения могут присоединяться посредством подчинительных союзов: **Неодолимая, хотя и тихая, сила увлекала меня (Т.);**
Но если определение, присоединяемое подчинительным союзом, является однородным по отношению к предшествующему определению **и не носит характера уточнения (смыслового и интонационного)**, то после него запятая не ставится: **Перед нами поставлена трудная, зато интересная задача** [см. § 12, п. 6].

Разграничение этих случаев зависит **от воли пишущего.**

Таким образом, обособление является факультативным.

***Получены важные, хотя и не итоговые сведения.*** Сравнить: Получены важные, но не итоговые сведения. Здесь скорее однородные отношения.

**Неодолимая, хотя и тихая, сила увлекла меня.** А здесь попутное замечание, которое автор относит к уточняющим и поэтому обособляет.